# How to cache listobjects with Cachecontrol and etag?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, response, cache-control

What is the most efficient or a possible way to give the objects in a list an etag? Currently I am getting all objects with one database query, but I cannot give an etag to every object, because its just one request. So at the moment, if one object changes, the whole list needs to be called from database.

```
@GET
public Response getPlayers( @Context Request request) { 
    List<Player> players = database.getAll();
    ........
}
```